# How to detect when chromium/ electron is done zooming?

Tags: electron, chromium

I'm working in Electron and trying to detect when Electron is done executing Control + 0 function which brings the zoom of the window back to 100%. I have a menu like the 3 dot menu in the top right of chrome and want to have the zoom number update when i use control + 0.

However from what i've tried i've gathered that if i just add a keyboardevent listener like i did below the function i run to update the menus zoom will finish before electron/ chromium is done.

So how would i detect when this is done so I can execute my function accordingly?

```
public onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const key = event.key
    const control = event.ctrlKey

    if (control === true && key === '0') {
      this.updateCurrentZoom()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried other keyboard events, typically keypress and keyup?

Comment: If that's enough for you to _get_ the current zoom when the menu is opened, you can use [`contents.getZoomFactor`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsgetzoomfactorcallback) or its relatives

Comment: @ghybs - The issue is not getting Ctrl+0 that works perfectly fine, the issue is rather that my event will fire independently and before Chromium/ Electron executes its internal Ctrl+0 event

Comment: @pergy - The issue is not getting the value, it's that i can't intercept and execute a function after Chromium/ Electron executes their internal Ctrl+0 function to reset zoom to 100%.

Comment: @DanielTurcich I understand what you are saying, but still, you may not realize the timing difference between those events.

Comment: @ghybs What do you mean i don't realize the timing differences? I'm said explicitly that this is not working because it has no context of the actual chromium event. Which is what i'm trying to find how to execute after. The chromium event is what i'm trying to find and execute a function afterwards, which as stated is separate from my event listener.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently added to the window title of my Electron apps a suffix string showing the current zoom factor.

In order to detect the zoom change (including the zoom reset), I had to use the window 'resize' event which is, surprisingly enough, not only triggered when the window size gets modified, but also when the zoom level changes!

```
// Renderer process
const { webFrame } = require ('electron');
window.addEventListener
(
    'resize',
    (event) =>
    {
        // Returns 1.0 for 100%
        let zoomFactor = webFrame.getZoomFactor ();
        updateCurrentZoom (zoomFactor);
    }
);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fire except for when resizing. Maybe you're using a later version of Electron and that was something added? I'm on 1.8.7

Comment: Indeed, I'm using the latest Electron version 3.0.4. I guess it depends on the new underlying Chromium version 66.

Comment: Actually, I did a few tests on a clone of the Electron Quick Start app, and it does work also in 2.0.4 and 1.8.7, but I forgot to mention that I'm on macOS...

Comment: Maybe it's to do with macOS? Because on Windows 10 it's definitely only firing when the window resizes saddly... And I still can't find anything else about it :/ 

You'd think someone else would've ran into this before. Or i'm just not the best at finding things either way.